# Can a 4mb size for single html file cause error?

Tags: html, upload-max-filesize

Can a file size of =+ 4mb for single HTML files without images cause a code 500 error?
And, if so, how could I avoid that?

Comment: I'm not clear: is this a static file served by your server, or a page with some dynamic content? Or you've tagged this 'upload-max-filesize' - is it something you're uploading with an HTTP POST? But either way I don't think we can say for sure: no, any halfway modern server under reasonable load should have no problems streaming a page that size, and conventionally an upload-too-large error should be a 400-series code, probably just 400 itself. If you're getting 500, are there any errors in the web server logs or e.g. PHP logs if you're using PHP?

Comment: this is a static file, old pdf converted to html, on my website. No error when uploding them, just when they are served. I'm just trying to rule out a possibility.

Comment: OK, then you'll need to check the server logs or debug your server process to see what's happening. It not impossible that the file size is a factor in the error, particularly if your server is under heavy load, but it would need some very odd circumstances, or you're using an unusual server that's e.g. loading all content into memory to serve rather than streaming from disk, which again might be an issue under load.

Comment: the server has normal traffic and the site the same. Also, this error is recurrent, so I assume circumstances are normal. I haven't been able to find the error logs yet. That would certainly help.

Comment: HTTP Error code 500 means Internal Server Error. This can be pretty much to anything! I would not expect it to be related to the file size though. Modern servers can server GBs of download files, so 4MB is rather small.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net Check max-request-size .. 
I think the reason for the 500 error is that reaching the max-request-size is a system error.

Comment: it's a .com page, would that apply anyway?

Comment: He means [.NET](https://www.microsoft.com/net), Microsoft's runtime and libraries, not the .net top level domain. So I guess you're not using that, or C# or Visual Basic.NET.

Comment: LOL, sorry I'm a newbie. The server runs Linux, so yes, no Microsoft runtime libraries. I have looked in the control panel but haven't found any setting for maximum-request size. Where would that data be set?